# Could not render images in PDF (Puppeteer)

Tags: html, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I have a server in my local network with the following domain : http://test

and image from page looks like: http://test/images/img.png

my puppeteer code is like the following (using mu for templating) 
the problem is that I see the images in a few computers in the network and in my computer, I don't see it 
how can I make sure the images rendered correctly

```
    try {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
        })
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })
        buffer = await page.pdf({format: 'A4'})
    } finally {
        try {
            browser.close()
        } catch (err) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: How you are solve it?